# Haskell: prime number detector

Tags: haskell, recursion

I am trying to learn Haskell and I am stuck at a problem with recursion. What i need to do is find wether a number is prime or not. This is my attempt so far. but it does not work. It gives "False" for non prime numbers, but it gets stuck on an infinite loop when the number is prime.

```
isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime num = primeTest num 2
    where
      primeTest :: Int -> Int -> Bool
      primeTest num x
            | x == num      = True
            | num `mod` x == 0 = False
            | otherwise    = primeTest num (x + 1)
               where 
                 x = 2
```

Answer (score 3):

You dont need

```
where 
  x = 2
```

This is why it is running into an infinite loop. For example, Consider the input 2, `num mod x` will return 0, so it will return False. Consider input 5, `num mod x` will return 1 (since `x` is 1 in this case). So, it goes to the otherwise part, where `primeTest num (x + 1)` is called with assigning `x = 2`. So, always this loop will run infinitely, with the `x` value 3.

Comment: Thank you so much. I suffered quite a headache trying to see what was wrong when it was plain obvious. I really apreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

The `where x=2` at the end causes every instance of `x` after `primeTest num x` to be 2, regardless of the value that was passed to `primeTest` in the `x` "slot."  Get rid of the `where x=2`.